# AngularJS polling service not continuously updating controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am trying to update a controller continuously using a polling service.  I have the service working and can verify it is polling and getting new data properly.  What I can't get working is the updating of the controller that uses that service.

Here is what I have:

```
cadApp.controller('statsController', function ($scope, DashboardStats) {
    $scope.data = DashboardStats.data.response;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(DashboardStats.data.response));    
});

cadApp.run(function (DashboardStats) { });

cadApp.factory('DashboardStats', function ($http, $timeout) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };
    var url = "Ajax/CADAjax.aspx";
    var params = { "Command": "GetDashboardStats" };

    var poller = function () {
        $http.post(url, Object.toparams(params))
     .then(function (responseData) {
         data.response = responseData.data[0];

         // This is working
         console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData.data[0]));
         data.calls++;
         $timeout(poller, 10000);
     });
    };
    poller();

    return {
        data: data
    };
});
```

The UI never updates with the current object returned by the polling service.  My guess is that the return statement in the service isn't right.  It is only returning the mostly empty object declared at the top of the service.

How do I get the service to automatically update the controller whenever the http response comes back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got to `return` some of that data - and dont put the `timeout` logic in the service - that should be contained in the controller code. You can refactor to handle the response in the controller and the data call contained in the service:

```
cadApp.controller('statsController', function ($scope, $timeout, DashboardStats) {
    pollData();

    function pollData() {
        DashboardStats.poll().then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $timeout(pollData, 10000);
        });
    }
});

cadApp.factory('DashboardStats', function ($http, $timeout) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var url = "Ajax/CADAjax.aspx";
    var params = { "Command": "GetDashboardStats" };
    var data = { response: { }, calls: 0 };

    var poller = function () {
        return $http.post(url, Object.toparams(params)).then(function (responseData) {
            data.calls++;
            data.response = responseData.data[0];

            return data;
        });
    };

    return {
        poll: poller
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome!  I thank you.  I am a few hours into using Angular and I am loving it, just got to break free of my jQuery flow habits.  What is funny is that I was just about to comment that it worked except for the missing [0] index of that JSON array that is returned.  You edited your post too fast for me to comment :)  Thanks again!

Comment: @tymeJV why do you advise that timeout logic be contained in the controller code, as opposed to in the service? I am trying to determine a best practice for polling with angular.

Answer (score 3):

You need a callback in your factory and then return a function which will be used in your controller:

```
cadApp.factory('DashboardStats', function ($http, $timeout) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var data = { response: { }, calls: 0 };
    var url = "Ajax/CADAjax.aspx";
    var params = { "Command": "GetDashboardStats" };

    var poller = function (success) {
        $http.post(url, Object.toparams(params)).then(function (responseData) {
            data.response = responseData.data[0];
            success(data);
            data.calls++;
            $timeout(poller, 10000);
        });
    };

    return {
        poller: poller
    };
});
```

and then in your controller invoke the `poller` function and inside the `success` callback update your scope:

```
cadApp.controller('statsController', function ($scope, DashboardStats) {
    DashboardStats.poller(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```